# iMac as PS3 Screen

Tags: imac, display, games

I was considering getting a PS3 and I'm planning to connect it to my 27" iMac (late 2009 model). What is the best way to connect the two?

UPDATE: Considering the price of all the adapters and the fact that the PS3 doesn't support my iMac's resolution I decided to get an other display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HDMI to display port adapter should work with the iMac in question since it supports [Target Display Mode](http://blog.macsales.com/10899-target-display-mode-and-thunderbolt).

Here is an example of an HDMI to Display Port adapter the [StarTech HDMI to DisplayPort Active Converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004I6IYSM). Lastly video wise you would need a [display port to mini display port cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024606&p_id=6006&seq=1&format=2) to plug into the iMac.

As for the audio you can use a [optical audio cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSLINK) from the PS3 optical audio out to the line in port on the back of the iMac.

Or you can use a [Digital Audio To Analog Audio Converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0013LWK3A) and a send the output to the iMac, amplifier, or computer speakers with the proper adapter cable.

**Word of caution:** Depending on the speed of the active HDMI to DisplayPort converter, the audio and video may not be in sync.

**Note:** that is will not work with  [any iMac that has Thunderbolt](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3775) since these macs can only provide DisplayPort output capabilities, and that may be spotty at best according to [Thunderbolt port to mini Display-Port cable](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2766642?start=0&tstart=0), where there were reports of graininess.

Comment: What about sound?

Comment: Be aware that this might not work with a newer Thunderbolt iMac.

Answer (score 1):

This [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lkpBhhS4c8) suggests that the [Belkin AV360](http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=508267) can be used to connect a PS3 and an iMac. However, the AV360 seems pretty pricy - currently listed on the site at $149.99.

Another [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kmbzi3mV36s) shows a different solution - a HDMI to Mini Display Converter. However, the author noted that the Mini Display port only takes video, not audio, so not a perfect solution.

Comment: Note for future reference this will not work on a Thunderbolt iMacs

Comment: @MrDaniel, very good point...